# C UDP networking, extract numbers from datagram message

Tags: c, udp, packet, datagram

I am developing a network software as a part of an university exam. The software is almost finished, but actually I am finishing the concurrent part (with fork()).
My needs are to exchange between client and server these two messages as handshake.
Here an example:
PING:3506:DOWNLOAD
PONG:5605

Here my way to handle these messages:
On client side, that is the host who sends PING:3506:DOWNLOAD, I wrote

```
int *childLocalPort;
childLocalPort = malloc(sizeof(int));
childLocalPort[0] = (SERV_PORT_OFFSET + getPort(&portArray, &pidArray, &arrayCounter, cpid));

char *pingProcedureString;
pingProcedureString = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
strcpy(pingProcedureString, "PING:");

char *itoaPortBuffer;
itoaPortBuffer = malloc(6*sizeof(char));
itoa((childLocalPort[0]), itoaPortBuffer, 10);
strcat(pingProcedureString, itoaPortBuffer);
strcat(pingProcedureString, ":DOWNLOAD");
if (sendto(sockfd, pingProcedureString, strlen(pingProcedureString), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
{
    perror("errore in sendto1");
    exit(1);
}
free(itoaPortBuffer);
free(pingProcedureString);



n = recvfrom(sockfd, buff, MAXLINE, 0, NULL, NULL);
buff[n] = 0;
if(strcmp(buff,"PONG"))
{
    int *childRemotePort;
    childRemotePort = malloc(sizeof(int));
    strtok(buff, ":");
    childRemotePort[0] = ntohs(strtok(NULL, ":"));

    printf("Remote port is %d\n", childRemotePort[0]);



    close(pipeLocalPort[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
    write(pipeLocalPort[1], childLocalPort, sizeof(int)
    close(pipeLocalPort[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
    close(pipeRemotePort[0]);
    write(pipeRemotePort[1], childRemotePort, sizeof(int));
    close(pipeRemotePort[1]);
}
```

On server side, that is the host who sends PONG:5605, I wrote

```
if ((n > 0) && strcmp(recvline,"PING"))
{
    int *childRemotePort;
    childRemotePort = malloc(sizeof(int));
    strtok(recvline, ":");
    char *buffTemp;
    buffTemp = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(buffTemp,strtok(NULL, ":"));
    childRemotePort[0] = ntohs(atoi(buffTemp));
    strtok(recvline, ":");
    printf("Remote child client port is: %d\n", childRemotePort[0]);
}
```

As you can notice, the PONG part is missing, because I would like to focus on first non working part. The server receives correctly (as I can see from Wireshark) the message PING:3506:DOWNLOAD, but he tells me he received 19476 instead of 3506, and this is not true.
I also noticed that if I try to send numeric messages without converting them into network byte order, things get worse. I am fighting with this from many days, and I don't know anymore what to think about.

Comment: 1) Your buffers are too small. 2) No need to allocate them using malloc(), you can easily allocate a few hundred byte sized buffers on the stack. 3) you assume that the network packets are nul-terminated. They are not. 4) oops, I overlooked `buff[n] = 0;
` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you'r sending a PING from client , the client fails  to do a  `ntohs`  on the integer port before converting to ascii but while receiving at server you do a `ntohs`  , i think this is causing the error.  Doing something on these lines on the client PING side might help however this is still error prone if the *endianness*  of server and client is different.

```
char *itoaPortBuffer;
itoaPortBuffer = malloc(6*sizeof(char));
itoa(ntohs(childLocalPort[0]), itoaPortBuffer, 10);
strcat(pingProcedureString, itoaPortBuffer);
strcat(pingProcedureString, ":DOWNLOAD");
```